# Django Heroku database error ENGINE not provided

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I am having issues with dj_database_url using django 1.5.4

I have followed the documentation and read quite a few stack overflow questions regarding the same error.

Everything works locally with foreman start, but on Heroku I get an error that ENGINE is not provided.

I have also tried filling in my heroku postgres database_url manually inside `dj_database_url`.

**Relevant settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'mydb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        #'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        #'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

if os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', None):
   import dj_database_url
   DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

Any advice would be met with much gratitude

**EDIT**:
Okay, so to help debug I added the line print DATABASES, it prints out:

```
{'default': {'PASSWORD': None, 'USER': None, 'NAME': 'postgres://<userpassetc>}', 'HOST': None, 'PORT': None}}
```

So it looks like ENGINE really isn't being provided and dj_database_url is doing something *funky*  BUT WHy!?! Any ideas?

It clearly finds my database and inserts it's value into 'NAME,' but why is it not showing a value for 'ENGINE' .

**EDIT**

Okay,
I found a sort of *Hacked answer.*  If anyone knows a better solution please let me know and I will mark it as correct. :)

I simply added an if statement like I had before, and manually filled in the information, because it seems that the problem has to do with dj_database_url not injecting the values correctly.  I'm not sure.  but heres what I put in my settings right under the normal DATABASE configuration.

**settings.py**

```
if os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', None):
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'dbnamefromheroku',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
            'USER': 'dbuserfromheroku',
            'PASSWORD': 'dbpassfromheroku',
            'HOST': 'dbhostfromheroku',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
            'PORT': 'dbportfromheroku',                      # Set to empty string for default.
        }
    }
```

---

If in 8 hours there is no better answer I will add this and mark as correct.

Comment: Please be absolutely certain that the security information you posted is redacted or obfuscated, and if it is not, then please change your information on the server side immediately!

Comment: As a sanity check, can you (locally) set a DATABASE_URL (via `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://foo:bar@host:5432/db`) then check what `dj_database_url.config()` returns (e.g., via an interactive Django shell)? What you are doing looks correct, and I've had success with it before. Also - you could try defining DATABASE_URL in a .env file (DATABASE_URL=postgres://etc/etc - no export required). Foreman reads the .env and applies them as environment variables when spawning the different processes.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any of that. But you haven't posted exactly what your DATABASE_URL env var is, or how you're setting it.